# OpenSSH hostbased authentication - mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x58c400 is disallowed

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to set up hostbased authentication for a small subset of hosts. I think I've got all my ducks in a row:

- Copied the public keys to the `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` file
- Put all the hosts in to `/etc/shosts.equiv`
- Enabled `HostbasedAuthentication` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`
- Setuid the `/usr/lib64/ssh/ssh-keysign` binary and set `EnableSSHKeysign yes` in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file on the clients.

However, it still doesn't work. Running the server in debug mode I get the following output:

```
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.3.128.10.
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 137
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for kamil
debug3: mm_start_pam entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 45
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 3
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 45
debug1: PAM: initializing for "kamil"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "foo.bar.com"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug2: monitor_read: 45 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 3
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
debug2: monitor_read: 3 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: userauth-request for user kamil service ssh-connection method hostbased
debug1: attempt 1 failures 1
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method hostbased
debug1: userauth_hostbased: cuser kamil chost foo.bar.com. pkalg ssh-dss slen 55
debug3: mm_key_allowed entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 20
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 20
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x58c400
debug2: userauth_hostbased: chost foo.bar.com. resolvedname foo.bar.com ipaddr 10.3.128.10
debug2: stripping trailing dot from chost foo.bar.com.
debug2: auth_rhosts2: clientuser kamil hostname foo.bar.com ipaddr 10.3.128.10
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1031/1028 (e=0/0)
debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 21
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1031/1028 (e=0/0)
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed hostbased for kamil from 10.3.128.10 port 55105 ssh2
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x58c400 is disallowed
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 21
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug2: userauth_hostbased: authenticated 0
debug1: userauth-request for user kamil service ssh-connection method hostbased
debug1: attempt 2 failures 2
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method hostbased
debug1: userauth_hostbased: cuser kamil chost foo.bar.com. pkalg ssh-rsa slen 143
debug3: mm_key_allowed entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 20
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 20
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x58c400
debug2: userauth_hostbased: chost foo.bar.com. resolvedname foo.bar.com ipaddr 10.3.128.10
debug2: stripping trailing dot from chost foo.bar.com.
debug2: auth_rhosts2: clientuser kamil hostname foo.bar.com ipaddr 10.3.128.10
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1031/1028 (e=0/0)
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1031/1028 (e=0/0)
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed hostbased for kamil from 10.3.128.10 port 55105 ssh2
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x58c400 is disallowed
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 21
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 21
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug2: userauth_hostbased: authenticated 0
debug1: userauth-request for user kamil service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive
debug1: attempt 3 failures 3
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive
```

The crux of the problem seems to be the line:

```
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x58c400 is disallowed
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, major failure on my part. I had created `/etc/shosts.equiv` instead of `/etc/ssh/shosts.equiv` (see point 2 of my question). The reason it worked on some of my other systems was that they also had a residual `/etc/hosts.equiv` file from some previous work by a coworker.

Things work much better when the right files are in the right location. It took some use of `strace` on the server to find out what it was reading from what files to finally clue me in on the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helped to solve my problem. Another way would be to use `~/.shosts`, but this will only be interpreted if you put `IgnoreRhosts no` in the `sshd_config`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `EnableSSHKeysign` enabled on the client?  That was another piece that I needed to get hostbased auth working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on debian with an old host key ? openssh-blacklist package may be preventing use of keys that are affected by [the infamous SSL vulnerability](http://wiki.debian.org/SSLkeys).

Regenerate your host keys if this is the case.

Comment: No, these are freshly generated host keys and they work otherwise.